# Java project fails with "hazelcastInstance" errors and "undertowEmbeddedServletContainerFactory" errors

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, jhipster, hazelcast

I have a Java program with Jhipster (5.5.0) and Spring. When I run the site with `./mvnw` it works fine. For the past few months, when I compiled it with `mvn install -Pprod -DskipTests=true` and then ran it with `java -jar mysite.jar`, it worked fine. However. . . today the `java -jar mysite.jar` has been failing, giving the below errors.

This was first reported on another person's machine, as they were running the JAR fine the for the past 2 days, and then today it failed. So there were 0 code changes. I then tried it on my machine and its failing as well, even after recompiling it. I don't know anything about this "hazelcast" stuff so I'm not even using it - Jhipster or Spring must be using it. But I'm not sure why this would just randomly fail.

```
2019-01-23 11:58:57.953  INFO 51656 --- [           main] c.h.i.cluster.impl.MulticastJoiner       : [10.3.2.121]:5701 [dev] [3.7.8] Trying to join to discovered node: [10.3.2.160]:5701
2019-01-23 11:59:28.117  INFO 51656 --- [           main] c.h.i.cluster.impl.MulticastJoiner       : [10.3.2.121]:5701 [dev] [3.7.8] Trying to join to discovered node: [10.3.2.160]:5701
2019-01-23 11:59:58.303  INFO 51656 --- [           main] c.h.i.cluster.impl.MulticastJoiner       : [10.3.2.121]:5701 [dev] [3.7.8] Trying to join to discovered node: [10.3.2.160]:5701
2019-01-23 12:00:28.585  INFO 51656 --- [           main] c.h.i.cluster.impl.MulticastJoiner       : [10.3.2.121]:5701 [dev] [3.7.8] Trying to join to discovered node: [10.3.2.160]:5701
2019-01-23 12:00:58.739  INFO 51656 --- [           main] c.h.i.cluster.impl.MulticastJoiner       : [10.3.2.121]:5701 [dev] [3.7.8] Trying to join to discovered node: [10.3.2.160]:5701
2019-01-23 12:01:28.925  INFO 51656 --- [           main] c.h.i.cluster.impl.MulticastJoiner       : [10.3.2.121]:5701 [dev] [3.7.8] Trying to join to discovered node: [10.3.2.160]:5701
2019-01-23 12:01:59.091  INFO 51656 --- [           main] c.h.i.cluster.impl.MulticastJoiner       : [10.3.2.121]:5701 [dev] [3.7.8] Trying to join to discovered node: [10.3.2.160]:5701
2019-01-23 12:02:29.269  INFO 51656 --- [           main] c.h.i.cluster.impl.MulticastJoiner       : [10.3.2.121]:5701 [dev] [3.7.8] Trying to join to discovered node: [10.3.2.160]:5701
2019-01-23 12:02:59.358 ERROR 51656 --- [           main] com.hazelcast.instance.Node              : [10.3.2.121]:5701 [dev] [3.7.8] Could not join cluster in 300000 ms. Shutting down now!
2019-01-23 12:02:59.369  INFO 51656 --- [           main] com.hazelcast.core.LifecycleService      : [10.3.2.121]:5701 [dev] [3.7.8] [10.3.2.121]:5701 is SHUTTING_DOWN
2019-01-23 12:02:59.370  WARN 51656 --- [           main] com.hazelcast.instance.Node              : [10.3.2.121]:5701 [dev] [3.7.8] Terminating forcefully...
2019-01-23 12:02:59.370  INFO 51656 --- [           main] com.hazelcast.instance.Node              : [10.3.2.121]:5701 [dev] [3.7.8] Shutting down multicast service...
2019-01-23 12:02:59.372  INFO 51656 --- [           main] com.hazelcast.instance.Node              : [10.3.2.121]:5701 [dev] [3.7.8] Shutting down connection manager...
2019-01-23 12:02:59.376  INFO 51656 --- [           main] com.hazelcast.nio.tcp.TcpIpConnection    : [10.3.2.121]:5701 [dev] [3.7.8] Connection[id=1, /10.3.2.121:59390->/10.3.2.160:5701, endpoint=[10.3.2.160]:5701, alive=false, type=NONE] closed. Reason: TcpIpConnectionManager is stopping
2019-01-23 12:02:59.381  INFO 51656 --- [           main] com.hazelcast.instance.Node              : [10.3.2.121]:5701 [dev] [3.7.8] Shutting down node engine...
2019-01-23 12:02:59.390  INFO 51656 --- [           main] com.hazelcast.instance.NodeExtension     : [10.3.2.121]:5701 [dev] [3.7.8] Destroying node NodeExtension.
2019-01-23 12:02:59.391  INFO 51656 --- [           main] com.hazelcast.instance.Node              : [10.3.2.121]:5701 [dev] [3.7.8] Hazelcast Shutdown is completed in 21 ms.
2019-01-23 12:02:59.391  INFO 51656 --- [           main] com.hazelcast.core.LifecycleService      : [10.3.2.121]:5701 [dev] [3.7.8] [10.3.2.121]:5701 is SHUTDOWN
2019-01-23 12:02:59.443  WARN 51656 --- [           main] com.hazelcast.util.PhoneHome             : [10.3.2.121]:5701 [dev] [3.7.8] Could not schedule phone home! Most probably Hazelcast is failed to start.
2019-01-23 12:02:59.444  INFO 51656 --- [           main] com.hazelcast.instance.Node              : [10.3.2.121]:5701 [dev] [3.7.8] Node is already shutting down... Waiting for shutdown process to complete...
2019-01-23 12:02:59.448  WARN 51656 --- [           main] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start embedded container; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'undertowEmbeddedServletContainerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/EmbeddedServletContainerAutoConfiguration$EmbeddedUndertow.class]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'webConfigurer' defined in URL [jar:file:/Users/mike.knoth/Desktop/automationstation.war!/WEB-INF/classes!/com/odp/config/WebConfigurer.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 2; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'hazelcastInstance' defined in class path resource [com/odp/config/CacheConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.hazelcast.core.HazelcastInstance]: Factory method 'hazelcastInstance' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Node failed to start!
2019-01-23 12:02:59.449  INFO 51656 --- [           main] com.odp.config.CacheConfiguration        : Closing Cache Manager
2019-01-23 12:02:59.493 ERROR 51656 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application startup failed

org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start embedded container; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'undertowEmbeddedServletContainerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/EmbeddedServletContainerAutoConfiguration$EmbeddedUndertow.class]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'webConfigurer' defined in URL [jar:file:/Users/mike.knoth/Desktop/automationstation.war!/WEB-INF/classes!/com/odp/config/WebConfigurer.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 2; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'hazelcastInstance' defined in class path resource [com/odp/config/CacheConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.hazelcast.core.HazelcastInstance]: Factory method 'hazelcastInstance' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Node failed to start!
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.onRefresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:137)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:537)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:693)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:360)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:303)
    at com.odp.UiApp.main(UiApp.java:66)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:48)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:87)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:50)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.WarLauncher.main(WarLauncher.java:59)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'undertowEmbeddedServletContainerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/EmbeddedServletContainerAutoConfiguration$EmbeddedUndertow.class]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'webConfigurer' defined in URL [jar:file:/Users/mike.knoth/Desktop/automationstation.war!/WEB-INF/classes!/com/odp/config/WebConfigurer.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 2; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'hazelcastInstance' defined in class path resource [com/odp/config/CacheConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.hazelcast.core.HazelcastInstance]: Factory method 'hazelcastInstance' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Node failed to start!
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:564)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.getEmbeddedServletContainerFactory(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:199)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.createEmbeddedServletContainer(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:162)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.onRefresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:134)
    ... 14 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'webConfigurer' defined in URL [jar:file:/Users/mike.knoth/Desktop/automationstation.war!/WEB-INF/classes!/com/odp/config/WebConfigurer.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 2; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'hazelcastInstance' defined in class path resource [com/odp/config/CacheConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.hazelcast.core.HazelcastInstance]: Factory method 'hazelcastInstance' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Node failed to start!
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:749)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:189)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1193)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1095)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:513)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeansOfType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:519)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedServletContainerCustomizerBeanPostProcessor.getCustomizers(EmbeddedServletContainerCustomizerBeanPostProcessor.java:82)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedServletContainerCustomizerBeanPostProcessor.postProcessBeforeInitialization(EmbeddedServletContainerCustomizerBeanPostProcessor.java:72)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedServletContainerCustomizerBeanPostProcessor.postProcessBeforeInitialization(EmbeddedServletContainerCustomizerBeanPostProcessor.java:59)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsBeforeInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:409)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1620)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:555)
    ... 22 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'hazelcastInstance' defined in class path resource [com/odp/config/CacheConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.hazelcast.core.HazelcastInstance]: Factory method 'hazelcastInstance' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Node failed to start!
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:599)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1173)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1067)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:513)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:208)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1138)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1066)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:835)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:741)
    ... 38 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.hazelcast.core.HazelcastInstance]: Factory method 'hazelcastInstance' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Node failed to start!
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:189)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:588)
    ... 51 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Node failed to start!
    at com.hazelcast.instance.HazelcastInstanceImpl.<init>(HazelcastInstanceImpl.java:132)
    at com.hazelcast.instance.HazelcastInstanceFactory.constructHazelcastInstance(HazelcastInstanceFactory.java:218)
    at com.hazelcast.instance.HazelcastInstanceFactory.newHazelcastInstance(HazelcastInstanceFactory.java:176)
    at com.hazelcast.instance.HazelcastInstanceFactory.newHazelcastInstance(HazelcastInstanceFactory.java:126)
    at com.hazelcast.core.Hazelcast.newHazelcastInstance(Hazelcast.java:58)
    at com.odp.config.CacheConfiguration.hazelcastInstance(CacheConfiguration.java:75)
    at com.odp.config.CacheConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$1c92f609.CGLIB$hazelcastInstance$2(<generated>)
    at com.odp.config.CacheConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$1c92f609$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$3f6079fd.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:228)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:358)
    at com.odp.config.CacheConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$1c92f609.hazelcastInstance(<generated>)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:162)
    ... 52 common frames omitted
```

Comment: If you got Hazelcast, it's because you selected it as second level cache when generating your project. If you don't need caching, just disable it. The error says "[10.3.2.121]:5701 [dev] [3.7.8] Could not join cluster in 300000 ms. Shutting down now!" Have you tried to set log level to DEBUG on com.hazelcast* ? Maybe something in your environment is also listening on port 5701.

Comment: It looks like there is another instance of your app at `[10.3.2.160]:5701` and your local instance cannot join it. It might be helpful to check logs of `[10.3.2.160]:5701` to see why join was failed.